# Can we get information of pod deleted In Kubernetes Environment using Prometheus

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana-alerts

As we have setup Prometheus and Grafana using helm charts and we have configured email alerts for:

1. If a pod is created send me email alert
2. If a pod if in pending, error, unknown state send me email notification

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (
  kube_pod_created{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace=~".*" } > (time() - 600)
)
```

```
sum by (namespace, pod, node, instance, job, service) (
                    max by (namespace, pod, node, instance, job, service) (
                      kube_pod_status_phase{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints",namespace=~".*",phase=~"Pending|Unknown"}
                    )
                  * on (namespace, pod) group_left (node)
                    max by (namespace, pod, node, owner_kind, deployment, container) (kube_pod_owner{owner_kind!="Job"})
                )
              >
                0
```

We are trying to get email notification for deletion of a pod at present.

Can you suggest anything?

I tried some queries to get information about the pods which are deleted:

```
sum by (namespace, pod) (
  kube_pod_container_status_terminated{job="kubernetes-service-endpoints", namespace=~".*" } > (time() - 600)
)
```

but I am not able to get the proper information.